# Force actionbar relayout during configuration change

Tags: android, layout, android-actionbar

I have activity which isn't recreated during configuration change. In my action bar I have many "ifroom" buttons. When activity is created in portrait mode there are a few of them are shown in actionbar. In `onConfigurationChanged()` I call `getActivity().invalidateOptionsMenu()`, but after recreation there is the same set of icons as in previous screen orientation. So how can I force action bar relayout in such case?

Answer (score 0):

On your res folder create inside values folder a new xml called bools like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<resources>
   <bool name="nomal_layout">true</bool>
   <bool name="nomal_layout_land">false</bool>
   <bool name="large_layout">false</bool>
   <bool name="large_layout_land">false</bool>
</resources>
```

the example above is for a normal portrait layout (true), create more values folders with bools.xml according with the layouts you want to customize, like values-large-land (or use the new buckets http://android-developers.blogspot.com.br/2011/07/new-tools-for-managing-screen-sizes.html). Then on the onCreateOptionsMenu you check the layout and force (SHOW_AS_ACTION_ALWAYS) the itens you want to show:

```
// Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.????, menu);//the menu to inflate
MenuItem myMenuItem = menu.findItem(R.id.????);//the item you want to show in the specified layout
if (getResources().getBoolean(R.bool.large_layout_land)){
    myMenuItem.setShowAsAction(MenuItem.SHOW_AS_ACTION_ALWAYS)
}else{

}
```

This only works on Android >=11